# Installing ROOT(statistics program from CERN) on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cern-root

I'm trying to install ROOT v5.34 on Linux Ubuntu v12.04. After extracting the files and running the `configure` script, I type in `make` to initiate the installing process. However, after some time, I get the following error and any help in trying to fix this would be appreciated.

```
Install roots wrapper.
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create lib/python/genreflex/gccxmlpath.py: Permission denied
make: *** [lib/python/genreflex/gccxmlpath.py] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

---

`v5.34` : No issues here → → $ `tar xvf root_v5.34.34.source.tar.gz` ... 
Must be done as unpreviliged user in /home/[name]/tmp/ (Or other usable folder/ : Not the Desktop.)
 If you do the unpack of 'root_v5.34.34.source.tar.gz' with sudo or with a Windows© tool : You will experince "Permission denied".

The build : `cd root/ && ./configure && make`

Note : root v5.34 is an "old" version. Current is v6.06 https://root.cern.ch/downloading-root

---

---

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error you might wanna try, with the latest version. And this is what it helped me a lot.

The following list shows the programs required before you can install CEARN ROOT. In an environment with the following specifications.

I have sucessfully install ROOT on a Raspberry pi4

```
• Broadcom BCM2711, Quad core Cortex-A72 (ARM v8) 64-bit SoC @ 1.5GHz
• 8GB LPDDR4-3200 SDRAM
• 2.4 GHz and 5.0 GHz IEEE 802.11ac wireless, Bluetooth 5.0, BLE
• Gigabit Ethernet
• 2 USB 3.0 ports; 2 USB 2.0 ports.
• Raspberry Pi standard 40 pin GPIO header (fully backwards compatible with previous boards)
• 2 × micro-HDMI ports (up to 4kp60 supported)
• 2-lane MIPI DSI display port
• 2-lane MIPI CSI camera port
• 4-pole stereo audio and composite video port
• H.265 (4kp60 decode), H264 (1080p60 decode, 1080p30 encode)
• OpenGL ES 3.0 graphics
• Micro-SD card slot for loading operating system and data storage
• 5V DC via USB-C connector (minimum 3A *)
• 5V DC via GPIO header (minimum 3A *)
• Power over Ethernet (PoE) enabled (requires separate PoE HAT)

• Operating System: Ubuntu-MATE 20.04 LTS
• sd card 64gb Samsung endurance.
```

Prerequisites

```
sudo apt-get install git dpkg-dev cmake g ++ gcc binutils libx11-dev libxpm-dev libxft-dev libxext-dev

sudo apt-get install gfortran libssl-dev libpcre3-dev xlibmesa-glu-dev libglew1.5-dev libftgl-dev libmysqlclient-dev libfftw3-dev libcfitsio-dev graphviz-dev libavahi-compat-libdnssd-dev libldap2-dev python- dev libxml2-dev libkrb5-dev libgsl0-dev libqt4-dev
```

Optional

```
  sudo apt-get install gfortran libssl-dev libpcre3-dev \
  xlibmesa-glu-dev libglew1.5-dev libftgl-dev \
  libmysqlclient-dev libfftw3-dev libcfitsio-dev \
  graphviz-dev libavahi-compat-libdnssd-dev \
  libldap2-dev python-dev libxml2-dev libkrb5-dev \
  libgsl0-dev libqt4-dev
```

Installation

The latest version of ROOT is downloaded, which is a .tar.gz file, for this case the version “root_v6.24.00.source.tar.gz” will be installed.
The next step is to create a directory in any location, in this case it is the Desktop.
The folder to create is called CERN_Root

```
mkdir CERN_Root
```

the downloaded .tar.gz file is copied to this newly created directory.

```
 cp <file dir> Downloads / root_v6.20.04.source.tar.gz <new dir> CERN_Root/
 cd CERN_Root
```

unzip the .tar.gz file

```
tar -zxvf root_v6.20.04.source.tar.gz
```

It is unzipped and there should be a root-6.20.04 folder, now we create a directory for the for install.

```
 mkdir root-install
```

We access the root-build folder and load the necessary files with the cmake.

```
cmake ../root-6.24.00/
```

now we load all the libraries marking from which directory it should extract them, which is from the unzipped .tar.gz file, with the option `-Dall = ON`

```
sudo cmake ~/Desktop/CERN_Root/root-6.24.00/ -Dall=ON
```

Then run make with

```
make -jN (where N is the number of cores to be used for the installation)
```

then

```
 sudo make install
```

and finally after finished, type `root` in the terminal.